# Primeng selected dynamic p-tabPanel

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I used the TabView component from primeng, for the tab it's dynamic only the last tab is static, i used the property selected, for the dynamic tab `[selected]="'tab' + $index"`, the $index is the index of ngFor

The list contains one item, so the property selected will be `tab0`, so i defined the attribute `tab0` to `false`

the problem is that the 2 tab are selected although the attributes are defined as `false`

```
<p-tabView>
    <p-tabPanel header="{{category.categoryLabel}}" *ngFor="let category of categories; let $index=index" [selected]="'tab' + $index">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">{{'button.previous'|translate}}</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">{{'button.next'|translate}}</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default">{{'button.reset'|translate}}</button>
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="{{'tab.getProduct'|translate}}" [selected]="tab">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">{{'button.next'|translate}}</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default">{{'button.reset'|translate}}</button>
    </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>


 public tab0: boolean = false;
 public tab: boolean = false;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use activeIndex instead of selected if tabs are dynamic. PrimeNg also recommended the same.

```
<button type="button" pButton icon="fa fa-chevron-up" (click)="openPrev()"></button>
<button type="button" pButton icon="fa fa-chevron-down" (click)="openNext()"></button>

<p-tabView [activeIndex]="index">
    <p-tabPanel header="Header 1">
        Content 1
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Header 2">
        Content 2
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Header 3">
        Content 3
    </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

In ts file you can set the active index value any where or inside anymethod.

```
export class TabViewDemo {

    index: number = 0;

    openNext() {
        this.index = (this.index === 2) ? 0 : this.index + 1;
    }

    openPrev() {
        this.index = (this.index === 0) ? 2 : this.index - 1;
    }

}
```

See the **Programmatic Control** at this link [Primeng](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tabview)